# finding middle character in string using regex only

Tags: c#, java, regex

How can I find middle character with regex only

For example,this shows the expected output

`Hello` -> `l`

`world` -> `r`

`merged` -> `rg` (see this for even number of occurances)

`hi` -> `hi`

`I` -> `I`

I tried

```
(?<=\w+).(?=\w+)
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want the overhead of RegEx for this.

Comment: @BLaZuRE to learn regex

Comment: @NAMO This is not a good way to learn regexes. Learn how to use them on situations where you need them.

Comment: @NAMO you can read about Regex here http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: Regexes don't solve every problem. In general they are very bad at solving problems that require counting, or remembering numbers.

Comment: The right way to learn about regexes is to read a good book on the subject; e.g. Aho, Sethi & Ullman, or Freidl.  Freidl is more practical ... but the former (and similar) covers the theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions cannot count in the way that you are looking for. This looks like something regular expressions cannot accomplish. I suggest writing code to solve this.

Comment: +1 - So far, this is the only Answer that actually answers the question.  The OP specifically wants to do it using a regex ... to understand the limits of regexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str="Hello";
String mid="";
int len = str.length();
if(len%2==1)
    mid= Character.toString(str.getCharAt(len/2));
else
    mid= Character.toString(str.getChatAt(len/2))+ Character.toStringstr.getCharAt((len/2)-1));
```

This should probably work.

Comment: Adding to chars together doesn't result in concatenation (even in reverse order). Anyway OP needs regex-only way.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "jogijogi";
        int size = s.length() / 2;
        String temp = "";
        if (s.length() % 2 == 0) {
            temp = s.substring(size - 1, (s.length() - size) + 1);
        } else if (s.length() % 2 != 0) {
            temp = s.substring(size, (s.length() - size));
        } else {
            temp = s.substring(1);

        }

        System.out.println(temp);
    }
```

Comment: Does not answer the question ... especially if you consider the OP's stated reason he asked it.

Answer (score 0):

*Related:* **[How to match the middle character in a string with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051651/how-to-match-the-middle-character-in-a-string-with-regex)**

---

The following regex is based on [@jaytea's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051651/how-to-match-the-middle-character-in-a-string-with-regex#comment81446171_28052126) and works well with e.g. PCRE, Java or C#.

```
^(?:.(?=.+?(.\1?$)))*?(^..?$|..?(?=\1$))
```

[Here is the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/As8hIf/4) and [a .NET demo at RegexPlanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyp027k3r) (click the green ".NET" button)

Middle character(s) will be found in the *second* [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). The goal is to capture two middle characters if there is an even amount of characters, else one. It works by a *growing capture* towards the end (*first group*) while [lazily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) going through the string until it ends with the captured substring that grows with each repitition. `^..?$` is used to match strings with one or two characters length.

This "growing" works with *capturing* inside a [repeated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) by placing an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) [reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to the *same group* together with a freshly captured character into that group ([further reading here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644267/5527985)).

A PCRE-variant with [`\K` to reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) and *full matches*: [`^(?:.(?=.+?(.\1?$)))+?\K..?(?=\1$)|^..?`](https://regex101.com/r/uAKR0G/1)

---

Curious about the "easy solution using *balancing groups*" that [@Qtax mentions in his question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28051651/5527985).