# How can I use Regex in Java to get the first and middle character of the username part of an email?

Tags: java, regex

I want to mask email address like below.

Input:
test@gmail.com; helloworld@yahoo.co.in; ibibo@hotmail.com;

Output:
t*s*@gmail.com; h**w**@yahoo.co.in; i*i**@hotmail.com;

Below Regex is excluding domain part but masking all characters in first part, except first character.

input.replaceAll("(?<=.{1}).(?=[^@]*?@)","X");

like helloworld@yahoo.co.in to hxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.co.in

I wanted to print a character in middle of the local-part like hxxxxWxxxx@yahoo.co.in

FYI -

I want to get first and middle character (random middle character in case of even length(4/6/8 characters).

Like below.

Alpha@gmail.com -> A *& p characters*

Beta@gmail.com --> B & t

Kat@yahoo.com -> k&a or k&t

Comment: The "hard part" of what you're looking for is [How to match the middle character in a string with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28051651/11107541)

Comment: Also, I don't understand your example "_Kat@yahoo.com -> k&a or k&t_" why "k&t"? The middle character of the username there is pretty unambiguously "a". And why is your "_Beta@gmail.com --> B & t_" not instead "B&t or B&e"?