# Why does this comparison return ? (Regular Expressions)

Tags: regex

```
1)mysql> SELECT 'aXbc' REGEXP '[a-dXYZ]';                 -> 1
2)mysql> SELECT 'aXbc' REGEXP '^[a-dXYZ]$';               -> 0    
3)mysql> SELECT 'aXbc' REGEXP '^[a-dXYZ]?$';              -> 0   // 0 or 1
4)mysql> SELECT 'aXbc' REGEXP '^[a-dXYZ]+$';              -> 1   // 1 or more
5)mysql> SELECT 'aXbc' REGEXP '^[a-dXYZ]*$';              -> 1   //0 or more
```

I'm confused about the second comparison. Doesn't it mean that a string which starts with [a-dXYZ] and ends with [a-dXYZ]?

Or does it mean that a string which starts with [a-dXYZ] and ends with [a-dXYZ] whose length is 1? If this is true, using ^ and $ symbols like '^....$' (leftmost and rightmost) eliminates all substrings and analyses only the string as a whole - is that right?

Note: This is not a how can I make it question. I want to understand a cause and effect relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^[a-dXYZ]$` will match exactly one character which it either: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `X`, `Y`, `Z` and is the first character and the last. So your second observation is pretty straight on.

`^` means start of input and `$` means end of input.

You can use `*` to repeat 0 or more times or `+` to repeat 1 or more times:

```
^[a-dXYZ]+$
```

If you want to match a string starting and ending with `[a-dXYZ]`, you could use the following:

```
^[a-dXYZ].*[a-dXYZ]$
#        ^ Match anything zero or more times
```

In some regex implementations you can use the `m` modifier which will make `^` and `$` match beginning and end of lines, rater than input, consider the following Perl snippet:

```
s/^1+$/_/gm
```

It will replace all lines only consistent of ones:

```
% seq 1 11 | tac | perl -p0e 's/^1+$/_/gm'
_
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
_
```

Comment: ^[a-dXYZ]$ it looks for 1 length string as a whole, doesn't consider substrings ?

Comment: It will match a input which is 1 character long.

Comment: am i allowed to use ^ $ symbols in the middle of string if so does '^[B](.*)(^[K]$)(.*)[B]$' return true with BAAKAAB. or it depends on where to use ?(oracle sql, mysql , java)

Comment: @BurakKarasoy As I said before: `^ and $ will match beginning and end of input`. So using these metacharacters in the middle of a match will make the match invalid.

Comment: answer of this question confused me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467249/regular-expressions-middle-of-string  and also thanks for your time.

Comment: @BurakKarasoy That answer uses something called lookarounds: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: owner of that question should have mentioned that in the question.Thanks again for your effort